# How can I move application windows using Autokey?

Tags: python, linux, autokey

I'm attempting to resize and relocate various windows I use for work using Autokey to make my morning a little faster. From what I've googled, Autokey uses python to run its scripts. I've also seen half a dozen programs that could do the job for me, but I'm trying to do this with only the tools I have available to me.

I don't necessarily need it spelled out to me. Any direction to the right documentation would help, or a link to a similar script.  I'm currently running fedora 20, and open my windows with a little shell script:

```
google-chrome "http://google.com/"&
google-chrome  "http://leafdns.com/"&
pidgin&
konsole --noclose -e &
autokey-gtk&
gedit "test"&
```

As far as I can tell, there's nothing I can do in this shell script that can handle window movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe wmctrl is what you're looking for. An example using gedit and a script to get the window id:

```
gedit --new-window &
sleep 1
get_window_id gedit
wmctrl -i -r "$window_id" -e 0,1025,0,953,1000
```

(example pulled from [here](http://movingtofreedom.org/2010/08/10/arranging-windows-from-the-gnulinux-command-line-with-wmctrl/), which also shows you how to create the get_window_id script)

To understand how to get the window id, run the following

```
wmctrl -l
```

You will get a list of all detected windows and their names (some will be named by the program's actual name, but not all; in Google Chrome's case it is the name of the currently open website, at least for me)

The first value (something like **0x03a00006**) is the window's id. It might not be the easiest solution, but it is one. As for how to invoke it through python, read up on system commands [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-execute-unix-linux-command-examples/).

The alternatives to wmctrl would have to be either xdotool or xprop, but I doubt they would be any easier to operate. You can also look into tiling window management, which might be a good alternative to all this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

this online manual describes the [resize_move command](https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting.Window-class.html):

```py
resize_move(self, title, xOrigin=-1, yOrigin=-1, width=-1, height=-1, matchClass=False)
```

( https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting.Window-class.html )

i use it into autoKey like so ( a example ):

```py
window.resize_move('0 A.D.', xOrigin=1908, yOrigin=-27, width=1922, height=1089, matchClass=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with AutoKey questions. You'd be quite welcome on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/autokey/autokey) if you ever want to stop by. By the way, your API link is outdated. The new one, Autokey.github.io/autokey is prettier and includes new functionality as it's generated from the source code of the current version.